# jquery dialog position badly affected by hide/show action

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

The following code intercepts a click on a radiobutton set, warns if the change will cause data deletion, and then hides a subform and shows another subform. All the actions occur, but the position of the dialog box is adversely affected by the hiding and showing of the various divs. This effect varies depending on which radiobutton is pressed first. The 'reuse' button, when clicked first, causes the dialog box to display off the page.

If I turn off the hide/show, the dialog box position is fine.

How do I fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("input[name='provenance']").ready(function(){ 
        var v=$("input[name='provenance']:checked").val();
        $('div#prov_container div.optcol2').not('#'+v).hide();
        $('#'+v).show(); 
    });

    // toggle hide/show of provenance field
    $("input[name='provenance']").live("click", function(){
        v=$(this).val();
        provwarning(v); //intercept choice and check for conflicts
        v=$(this).val();//may have changed due to provwarning

        $('div#prov_container div.optcol2').not('#'+v).hide();//AFFECTS dialog POSITION

        $('#'+v).show();//AFFECTS dialog POSITION

    });

     //determine if user choice will clobber existing data
     //warn user
     //continue or revert user choice to previous value
    provwarning=function(changingto){
        c= $('input[name="cross_id"]').val()? 'Cross': false; 
        d=$('input#del_id').val()? 'Delivery':false;
        r=$('input#reuse_id').val()? 'Reuse': false;
        prov_was= c||d||r;
        if(!prov_was)return; //prov_was is 'Unknown', so there is no conflict
        if(prov_was==changingto) return; //no change, so no worries

        cw=(changingto=='Provenance')? 'unknown' : (changingto=='Delivery') ? 'delivered' : (changingto=='Reuse') ? 'reused' : 'bred onsite';
        ww=(prov_was=='Provenance')? 'unknown' : (prov_was=='Delivery') ? 'delivered' : (prov_was=='Reuse') ? 'reused' : 'bred onsite';
        msg="If you change the provenance to '"+cw+"' the current provenance, '"+ ww +"', will be deleted.";

        m='<div id="modalpop">'+msg+'</div>'; 
        $(m).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            title: 'Conflict with current Provenance',
            buttons: {
                "Continue": function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                    var $radio = $('input[name="provenance"]');
                    $radio
                        .removeAttr("checked")
                        .filter('[value="' + prov_was + '"]')
                        .prop("checked", true)
                        .click();

                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Your example link gives 403 forbidden error

Comment: @eagerMoose: thanks for letting me know. It looks like the admin has external IPs blocked. I will look for another place to put it.

Comment: @mblase, the link is active now.

Comment: Well, among other things, your dialog div (or divs?) aren't getting reused. Every time you open a dialog, it generates a new div, and just hides it on close, but it never gets reused.

Comment: @eagerMoose: I actually put that there so I wouldn't need to add the function that I do use. I can edit to include the function, but it doesn't affect the position issue. I've also used a `<div id='modalpop'>` hardcoded into the html.  Same position issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the answer lies in the order of events. In the original code, the `provwarning` function is called from inside a function. `provwarning` displays a dialog box.  But in the meantime the calling function has already done the hide/show action. If the user clicks 'Continue', the dialog box goes away. If the user clicks 'Cancel', the dialog box resets the radio button set and triggers the original function again.

For the dialog position not to be affected by the hide/show actions, those actions must happen *after* the dialog box closes.  The only way I could ensure that this happens was by putting the hide/show calls *inside* the dialog button functions like this:

```
// toggle hide/show of provenance field
$("input[name='provenance']").live("click", function(){
        changingto=$(this).val();

        c= $('input[name="cross_id"]').val()? 'Cross': false; 
        d=$('input#del_id').val()? 'Delivery':false;
        r=$('input#reuse_id').val()? 'Reuse': false;
        prov_was= c||d||r;
        if(prov_was==changingto) return; //no change, so no worries
        if(!prov_was) {
           $('#'+changingto).show().siblings('.optcol2').hide();
           return; //prov_was is 'Unknown', so there is no conflict
        }

        cw=(changingto=='Provenance')? 'unknown' : (changingto=='Delivery') ? 'delivered' : (changingto=='Reuse') ? 'reused' : 'bred onsite';
        ww=(prov_was=='Provenance')? 'unknown' : (prov_was=='Delivery') ? 'delivered' : (prov_was=='Reuse') ? 'reused' : 'bred onsite';
        msg="If you change the provenance to <strong>'"+cw+"'</strong> the current provenance, <strong>'"+ ww +"'</strong>, will be deleted.";


        m=modalpop(msg); //make or reuse a div to show the dialog
        $(m).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            title: 'Conflict with current Provenance',
            buttons: {
               'Continue': function() {
                           $(this).dialog('close');
                           $('#'+changingto).show().siblings('.optcol2').hide(); //hide-show IN BUTTON
                        },

               'Cancel': function() {
                            var $radio = $('input[name="provenance"]');
                            $radio
                                .removeAttr("checked")
                                .filter('[value="' + prov_was + '"]')
                                .prop("checked", true);
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                            $('#'+prov_was).show().siblings('.optcol2').hide();//hide-show IN BUTTON
                       };
        });
 });
```

I wish I knew why the original code doesn't wait for the dialog to complete before applying the hide-show.